# Quartus II selected a signal as a clock in combinational circuit

Tags: vhdl, clock, intel-fpga, quartus

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ALU is
port(
    input1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    input2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    reset: in std_logic; --Asynchronous Reset
    operation: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    zero_flag: out std_logic;
ov_flag: out std_logic;
output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end ALU;

architecture hybrid of ALU is
-------------------------Component Declaration------------------------
component kogge_stone_adder is
port(
    input1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    input2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    ov_flag: out std_logic;
    zero_flag: out std_logic;
    output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end component;

component two_complement is
port(
    input: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    output: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end component;
----------------------End Component Declaration-----------------------


--------------------------Signal Declaration--------------------------
signal adder_in_1: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal adder_in_2: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal adder_ov_flag: std_logic;
signal adder_zero_flag: std_logic;
signal adder_output: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal input2_comp: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
-----------------------End Signal Declaration------------------------
begin

process(all)
begin
---------------------------------Reset-------------------------------
    if reset = '1' then
        output <= x"00000000";
        zero_flag <= '0';
        ov_flag <= '0';
----------------------------End Reset----------------------------------
    else
------------Case Statement to Perform the required operation-----------
        case operation is
            when "0000" => --ADD
                adder_in_1 <= input1;
                adder_in_2 <= input2;
                ov_flag <= adder_ov_flag;
                zero_flag <= adder_zero_flag;
                output <= adder_output;
            when "0001" => --SUBTRACT
                adder_in_1 <= input1;
                adder_in_2 <= input2_comp;
                zero_flag <= adder_zero_flag;
                ov_flag <= adder_ov_flag;
                output <= adder_output; 
            --when "0010" => --MULTIPLY
            when "0011" => -- COMPARE EQUAL
                adder_in_1 <= input1;
                adder_in_2 <= input2_comp;
                ov_flag <= adder_ov_flag;
                zero_flag <= adder_zero_flag;
                if adder_zero_flag = '1' then
                    output <= x"00000001";
                else
                    output <= x"00000000";
                end if;
            when "0100" => --COMPARE LESS THAN
                adder_in_1 <= input1;
                adder_in_2 <= input2_comp;
                ov_flag <= adder_ov_flag;
                zero_flag <= adder_zero_flag;
                if adder_output(31) = '1' then
                    output <= x"00000001";
                else
                    output <= x"00000000";
                end if;
            when "0101" => --COMPARE LESS THAN OR EQUAL
                adder_in_1 <= input1;
            adder_in_2 <= input2_comp;
            ov_flag <= adder_ov_flag;
            zero_flag <= adder_zero_flag;
            if adder_output(31) = '1' or adder_zero_flag = '1' then
                output <= x"00000001";
            else
                output <= x"00000000";
            end if;
        when "0110" => --SHIFT RIGHT
            output <= '0' & input1(31 downto 1);
        when "0111" => --SHIFT LEFT
            output <= input1(30 downto 0) & '0';
        when "1000" => --ARITHMECTIC SHIFT RIGHT
            output <= input1(31) & input1(31 downto 1);
        when "1001" => -- BITWISE AND
            and_gate: for counter in 0 to 31 loop
                output(counter) <= input1(counter) and input2(counter);
            end loop;
        when "1010" => -- BITWISE OR
            or_gate: for counter in 0 to 31 loop
                output(counter) <= input1(counter) or input2(counter);
            end loop;
        when "1011" => -- BITWISE XOR
            xor_gate: for counter in 0 to 31 loop
                output(counter) <= input1(counter) xor input2(counter);
            end loop;
        when "1100" => -- BITWISE XNOR
            xnor_gate: for counter in 0 to 31 loop
                output(counter) <= input1(counter) xnor input2(counter);
            end loop;
        when "1101" => -- BITWISE NOT
            not_gate: for counter in 0 to 31 loop
                output(counter) <= not input1(counter);
            end loop;
        when "1110" => --ROTATE RIGHT
            output <= input1(0) & input1(31 downto 1);
        when "1111" => --ROTATE LEFT
            output <= input1(30 downto 0) & input1(31);
        when others =>
            output <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";
            zero_flag <= 'Z';
            ov_flag <= 'Z';
    end case;
end if;
end process;
------------------------Component Instantiation-------------------------
adder: kogge_stone_adder port map(
    input1 => adder_in_1,
    input2 => adder_in_2,
    ov_flag => adder_ov_flag,
    zero_flag => adder_zero_flag,
    output => adder_output
);
complementer: two_complement port map(
    input => input2,
    output => input2_comp
);
----------------------End Component Instantiation-----------------------
end hybrid;
```

While synthesizing a combinational circuit, quartus II reported in timing analyzer that a signal called operation(1) is the clock and reported negative slack, operation is a 4-bit bus I really don't know why it chose this specific bit,so the question is **How can I remove the clock from the design or How can I tell quartus that this is a combinational circuit ?**

[image: Quartus II Combinational circuit problem]

This is the full RTL view:

[image: RTL VIEW 1]

This is zoomed RTL view (the rest of the rtl is the doing the same thing to the other bits):
[image: Zoomed RTL VIEW]

This message also appeared in the console during synthesis:
[image: console message]
Does the above message is the reason for quartus to assign a clock ?(Synthesize latches instead of combinational logic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Quartus toolset (and FPGA tools in general) are intended for synchronous design. Trying to use them to develop a purely asynchronous design requires a great deal of experience, and is still often an exercise in frustration.

Timing analysis in particular *requires* a clock, and if you don't assign one, the tools will try to pick a likely candidate — with less than optimal results, as you have found.

You're going to have to constrain every combination of input and output from your circuit independently if you want the synthesis tools to opimize the implementation correctly. This quickly becomes unmanageable for anything but the most trivial of circuits.

Note that this is a generic answer. If you want help with your specific problem, show us your code.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but in the RTL view there were latches, however I still don't see the use of the clock in presence of latches.

Comment: In FPGA, a latch is not just level trigger thing but it holds the previous state value because coder has reluctantly or purposefully didn't specify the else clause which infers a latch.